# TableViewCell show slowly

Tags: iphone

I have made a custom cell for my tableview with a another viewcontroller to add content to it.
But strangely the content show slowly. I means only the center line appear most of the time (sometime nothing), then playing with the cell and after a while, the rest of the content (total 3 lines) finally appear.

[image: Only the > appear!]

After a while,

[image]

All is there.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    eatEventTableViewCell *cell = (eatEventTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"expenseCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[eatEventTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"expenseCell"];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(eatEventTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.nameField.text = [[object valueForKey:@"descText"] description];
    cell.tagsField.text = [[object valueForKey:@"type"] description];
    cell.creationDateLabel.text = [eatAddViewController dateFormat:[[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description] :TRUE];
    if([eatExpenseType getSelectionValue :cell.tagsField.text :m_setting])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the data? Are you sure it's not your `fetchedResultsController` that is taking a long time to load?

Comment: Use Instruments to see what code is taking longer than expected.

Answer (score 1):

- Since you're fetching from Core Data, one possibility is that the fetching takes a long time. Are you working on a large database
- Another likely explanation is that you're performing some other CPU intensive tasks on the main thread. Every UI operations takes place on the main thread, and you may experience a lag in the display if the main thread is also busy with other tasks. You would then want to perform those other tasks on a background thread.